# What steps must be taken to ensure security before deployment of rails 5 app on github and heroku

Tags: security, authentication, github, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose I built a rails app with authentication as per Michael Hartl’s tutorial. Now suppose I want to push the app on to a private github repository and deploy to heroku to for use by the public

What step(s) should be undertaken prior to pushing to source control and heroku to ensure the app is secure?

To be clear, I am not talking about adding additional features (e.g. two factor authentication, minimum password complexity requirements etc), but I would like to know anything and everything the app developer must do once the app has been built in development prior to going live in production e.g. moving or removing certain files or lines of code, what to do with ‘secrets’ etc

As a starting point, I read [this](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/22/how-to-hack-a-rails-app-using-its-secret-token/) article (which is old) but it made me nervous about whether or not I’d completed the necessary steps to ensure the app is secure